# Can't find an option to turn off cellular data for an application on iPhone (iOS 14)

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to turn off cellular data for an application on iPhone running iOS 14, I know that you can go to `Cellular` section in `Settings` and there will be a list of applications including the options to turn the cellular data on or off, but I can't find my application in that list to turn it off. Can someone help me with this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Knowing what the app is might at least let someone else see if they can repro the condition.

Comment: Have you tried going to the app itself within settings? It should have a toggle there. Try searching the app name in the search box at the top of settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't stand this iPhone "feature", but for an app to appear in the list where you can turn cellular data *on* or *off*:

1. the app must be launched once with cellular data *on*;
2. sometimes it is not enough - you must not only launch the app, you must do something with it actively.

Though, it may be that for newer iPhones this is not longer the case.